# Merging two dataframes but different column values

Tags: r, merge, dataframe

Sorry I am new to R and would greatly appreciate some help with this. I am trying to merge the following two dataframes(labourproductivity and Depressiondframe) based on Time:

```
Time            LabourProductivity
1 2004 Q1   96.6
2      Q2   96.9
3      Q3   96.9
4      Q4   97.1
5 2005 Q1   97.6
6      Q2   99.0
```

and

```
Time    DepressionCount
1 2004          875
2 2004.25   820
3 2004.5    785
4 2004.75   857
5 2005          844
6 2005.25   841
```

Since they both have different values for time I do not know how to merge them. Ideally it would look like:

```
Time    DepressionCount LabourProductivity
1 2004  875             96.6
2 2004  820             96.9
3 2004  785             96.9
4 2004  857             97.1
5 2005  844             97.6
6 2005  841             99.0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If "df1", and "df2" are the first and second datasets, create a grouping index ("indx") based on the "Time" column of "df1".  Convert the "Time" column to similar format as in "df2" by using `ave` and `as.yearqtr`

```
library(zoo)
indx <-  cumsum(grepl('^\\d+', df1$Time))
df1$Time <- with(df1, as.numeric(ave(Time, indx, FUN= function(x)  {
        x[-1] <- paste (sub(' .*', '', x[1]), x[-1])
        as.yearqtr(x) })))
```

`merge` the datasets, and `transform` the "Time" column if needed

```
transform(merge(df1, df2), Time=trunc(Time))
#    Time LabourProductivity DepressionCount
#1 2004               96.6             875
#2 2004               96.9             820
#3 2004               96.9             785
#4 2004               97.1             857
#5 2005               97.6             844
#6 2005               99.0             841
```

Or using `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
 setDT(df1)[, TimeN:= as.numeric(as.yearqtr(c(Time[1L],
    paste(sub(' .*', '', Time[1L]), Time[-1L])))), 
      list(Grp=cumsum(grepl('^\\d+', Time)))][,
            Time:= TimeN][, TimeN:=NULL][]

 setkey(df1, Time)[df2][, Time:=trunc(Time)][]
 #   Time LabourProductivity DepressionCount
 #1: 2004               96.6             875
 #2: 2004               96.9             820
 #3: 2004               96.9             785
 #4: 2004               97.1             857
 #5: 2005               97.6             844
 #6: 2005               99.0             841
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(Time = c("2004 Q1", "Q2", "Q3", "Q4", "2005 Q1", 
"Q2"), LabourProductivity = c(96.6, 96.9, 96.9, 97.1, 97.6, 99
)), .Names = c("Time", "LabourProductivity"), class = "data.frame", 
row.names = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6"))

df2 <- structure(list(Time = c(2004, 2004.25, 2004.5, 2004.75, 2005, 
2005.25), DepressionCount = c(875L, 820L, 785L, 857L, 844L, 841L
 )), .Names = c("Time", "DepressionCount"), class = "data.frame", 
 row.names = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6"))
```

Comment: got the following Error: unexpected symbol in "labourproductivity$Time <- with(labourproductivity, as.numeric(ave(Time, indx, FUN= function(x)  {x[-1] <- paste (sub(' .*', '', x[1]), x[-1])as.yearqtr"

Comment: @DavidResch Can you try it on the data showed in my post?

Comment: Yes Fantastic it worked. My data for both series goes until the end of 2013 so shall i just add the rest of the values or is there a quicker way. Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: @DavidResch `ave` is pretty quick, For the `merge` part, you can use `dplyr` or `data.table` or all the methods in either one of those package

Comment: @DavidResch Updated with a possible data.table method.